# Get Recent Campaign Sends from Mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to pull the latest sends from all my campaigns in Mailchimp via the 3.0 API. The only way I seem to be able to do this is:

1) Search for a given member by email

```
/3.0/search-members?query=joe@example.com
```

2) Get the member ID and request their activity

```
3.0/lists/{LIST ID}/members/{USER ID}/activity
```

3) Pull the content of the email in their activity feed:

```
3.0/campaigns/{CAMPAIGN ID}/content
```

The problem with this is that I need to know the user's email in advance and then search by each user individually, meaning many wasted of API calls.

Is there an endpoint for campaigns that I can request the last sends for a given date range?

Answer (score 0):

The `/campaigns` endpoint returns campaigns for a given list and each returned object does include a `recipients` property.

You may also want to checkout:

```
/search-campaigns
```

And:

```
/reports/{campaign_id}/sent-to
```